# Ambiguous overload when writing an enum with an enum-base, but only with clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I would like to use operator<< to write an enum with a specified base type. To my surprise, it seems I must write out the operator myself. For example, the code I would like to write is

```
#include <iostream>
enum myenum : uint16_t
{
    X = 0,
};
int main ()
{
    std::cout << "Value is" << X << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc 4.8 and visual studio 2015 have no problems with this. clang++-3.6 errors with

```
# clang++-3.6 -std=c++11 -O0 ostream.cpp -o test.exe
ostream.cpp:18:29: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types
      'basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'myenum')
    std::cout << "Value is" << X << std::endl;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:181:7: note: 
      candidate function
      operator<<(unsigned short __n)
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:189:7: note: 
      candidate function
      operator<<(int __n);
      ^
      ... another 14 candidates along the same lines ...
```

In general, I'm inclined to believe clang when it comes to strict conformance, so maybe the use really is ambiguous. The enum certainly is convertible to other sorts of integers. I hoped that the compiler would prefer the version corresponding to the base type of the enum.

I can work around by using some other language feature instead of enum ... : uint16_t or by explicitly typing out the operator in which case clang is also content.

```
static inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, myenum const & s)
{
    out << static_cast<std::underlying_type<myenum>::type> (s);
    return out;
}
```

This looks absurd though. Is clang's behaviour expected or erroneous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang problem. Minimized repro:

```
enum myenum : unsigned short
{
    X = 0,
};

void f(unsigned short);
void f(int);
int main ()
{
    f(X);
    return 0;
}
```

[conv.prom]/4:

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.
>   Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type,
>   a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying
>   type.

[over.ics.rank]/4.2 - this bullet was added by [CWG1601](http://wg21.link/CWG1601) as a DR against C++11:

> Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact
>   Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better
>   conversion than a Conversion. Two conversion sequences with the same
>   rank are indistinguishable unless one of the following rules applies:
>
> - [...]
> - A conversion that promotes an enumeration whose underlying type is
>     fixed to its underlying type is better than one that promotes to the
>     promoted underlying type, if the two are different.

`myenum`->`unsigned short` and `myenum`->`int` have the same rank (Promotion). Per [over.ics.rank]/4.2, the first is better than the second. There's no ambiguity here.

OTOH, GCC silently calls the wrong overload (the `int` one), which isn't that much better.

Comment: The resolution to DR 1601 made it into C++14, so now both compilers are unambiguously wrong...

Comment: I had a play with this, and all three of gcc, clang, and MSVC get this wrong in a variety of ways, particularly once they have the choice of int or unsigned int: https://godbolt.org/z/o2YnRB

Comment: So it's not lost/forgotten, @T.C. logged this as a bug with gcc at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68957. I didn't find any existing bug report for clang or MSVC in a brief search, but there was a patch proposed for clang at https://reviews.llvm.org/D32251 that does not appear to have advanced.